# Doing some logic before calling the super constructor in Java

Tags: java

I know that in a derived Java class one may call the super constructor as the first command in the child's constructor. Python for example kindly allows in this case to do some custom logic before calling the super constructor.

My question is: In Java is there any way to achieve this, calling some commands before calling the super constructor? If not, what is the "Java way" of doing this in general?

Example use case: I am writing a game, and in the child class constructor I need to load some assets (only for that child class, not statically), and pass them to the parent constructor.

Comment: Could you give some examples?

Comment: @codeNinja: Example added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call static methods within the call to super() (e.g. super(initSomething()); if that method is static).

However if your logic is too complicated it might be best to use a static factory method which can then do a little bit more custom initialization before calling into a (private) constructor.

Answer (score -1):

> Invocation of a superclass constructor must be the first line in the subclass constructor.

Taken from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html). So, no you cannot perform logic before you call the super class's constructor in the way you asked.

Comment: OP knows that, he heed a alternative solution for this problem